# "The service “sshd” appears to be down" emails started randomly

Tags: cpanel, whm

I started receiving cPanel monitoring emails stating "The service "sshd" appears to be down" emails about an hour ago and do not understand why or how to resolve them.

I am running WHM/cPanel on a Rackspace server.  Does anyone have any experience with these alerts, why they started, and how to enable "sshd" using WHM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing here was accessible for me to do anything with.  I had to contact Rackspace and they were able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can restart your SSHD services through  WHM >> Restart Services >> SSH Server (OpenSSH)

Please try to restart it and check if you are still facing same issues.

Comment: I did try this after posting my question and it can not start.  I actually logged into rackspace and it appears rackspace is having trouble connecting with both of my servers.  I created a ticket there, but for now I believe this is a larger issue.

Comment: If you have KVM console access of your server, then you can check your SSH services status through KVM console.